# How to take two fetches and compare their data as variables whilst not getting any errors?

Tags: javascript

I want to take two different fetches, put them into a variable form so their important data can be used for something else other than just logging the data.

I'm trying to do this via window response async, however, I am currently at a dead end because though what I'm doing works on one strand of data, it doesn't work on two because of the JSON body stream already read error.

```js
let RESPONSE = window.Response.prototype.json;
window.Response.prototype.json = async function () {
  if (!('https://a/')) return RESPONSE.call(this)
  let x = await RESPONSE.call(this);
  if (!('https://b/')) return RESPONSE.call(this)
  let y = await RESPONSE.call(this);
  for (let detect in x) {
    if (x[detect] !== y[detect]) {
      console.log(x[detect]);
      console.log(y[detect]);
    }
  }
  return x;
  return y;
};
```

How can I keep the data in a variable form that can be used for something like this:

```js
for (let detect in x) {
  if (x[detect] !== y[detect]) {
    console.log(x[detect]);
    console.log(y[detect]);
  }
```

but whilst being able to have both variables defined at the same time? This would mean I would need to get past the body stream error while also keeping that core code. How can I do that?

Comment: Please properly format your code. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting can be of help :). Also, if possible, provide all of the code so it can actually be run.

Comment: Also, are you sure you know what you are doing? This might sound a bit rude (it's not supposed to ) but you are modifying the global `Response` object and even its prototype. This is generally considered bad practice at is breaks (for example) library code or code of your co-workers.

Comment: Anyway, am I correct in the assumption that you want to make two fetches and then compare their result?

Comment: It sort of looks like this has been copy-pasted from different code snippets. To point out a few issues with it: **1.** this condition `if (!('https://a/'))` is never going to be true, thus the code will never be executed. **2.** `RESPONSE2` is nowhere defined so `RESPONSE2.call(this)` will error. **3.** `return x; return y;` will lead to `x` being returned from the function. Everything after a `return` statement will be ignored. **4.** You don't have any calls to `window.Response.prototype.json` so none of the code you've provided will be executed, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you?

```js
async function doTwoRequestsAndCompareStatus() {
  const res1 = await fetch("https://fakejsonapi.com/fake-api/employee/api/v1/employees");
  const res2 = await fetch("https://fakejsonapi.com/fake-api/employee/api/v1/employees");
  const data1 = await res1.json();
  const data2 = await res2.json();

  console.log('both were equal?', data1.status === data2.status);
}

// Don't forget the actually call the function 
doTwoRequestsAndCompareStatus();
```

Although I would recommend this, both because it's cleaner and faster, as the fetches are executed at the same time and not sequentially.

```js
async function doTwoRequestsAndCompareStatus() {
  const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([
    fetch("https://fakejsonapi.com/fake-api/employee/api/v1/employees").then(r => r.json()),
    fetch("https://fakejsonapi.com/fake-api/employee/api/v1/employees").then(r => r.json()),
  ]);

  console.log('both were equal?', data1.status === data2.status);
}

// Don't forget the actually call the function 
doTwoRequestsAndCompareStatus();
```

If you find the first one easier to understand though, I would recommend using it .

Comment: @Neon I see that you have accepted my answer but in case you have any more questions, please get back to me in the comments :)!